# Composed of non differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

It will be possible to find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ non-differentiable at zero such that $f\circ g$ is differentiable at zero where $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $g(s)=\sqrt[3]s$?

I appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. If 
$$ h(s) = f(g(s)) = f(\sqrt[3]s) $$
 is differentiable
at zero then
$$
  f(x) = h(x^3)
$$
if differentiable at zero by the chain rule.